# codeigniter 404 page not found error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter.

Client gave the already developed codeigniter code to us. Its working fine in my local server.

While upload the files to my demo server it shows

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

in the index.php at the end there is the line as

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

If I echo anything before this line it is displayed. If I echo after this line nothing displayed.

Below is the htaccess lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demos/stallbook/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://domainname.com/demos/stallbook/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

In routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/Dashboard";
```

This code stops working in `core/CodeIgniter.php`

I analysed this code. Here they intitate the routing as

```
  $RTR =& load_class('Router', 'core');
  $RTR->_set_routing();

 // Set any routing overrides that may exist in the main index file
  if (isset($routing))
  {
     $RTR->_set_overrides($routing);
  }
```

This code stops working after `$RTR->_set_routing();` line.

I dont know what to do this. But in local server its working fine and good.

Please help me. Its totally frustrating.

Comment: is it different PHP version? And what's the version of Codeigniter?

Comment: @ Ye Lwin Soe: codeigniter version is 2.1.4. PHP Version 5.6.30

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add the line in the .htaccess files **rewritebase /demos/stallbook/** and check.
```

Let me know if it's not working...